# Change Component property through onClick

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a `ButtonGroup` with a few Buttons in it, and when one of the buttons gets clicked, I want to change its color, I kinda want to make them behave like radio buttons:

```
    <ButtonGroup>
      <Button
        variant={"info"}
        onClick={(e) => {
          ..otherFunctions..
          handleClick(e);
        }}
      >
        <img src={square} alt={".."} />
      </Button>
    </ButtonGroup>

    function handleClick(e) {
      console.log(e.variant);
    }
```

But that doesnt work, e.variant is undefined.

If it was just a single button I would have used `useState` and I would be able to make this work, but how do I make it work when there are multiple buttons, how do I know which button is clicked and change the variant prop of that button? And then revert the other buttons to variant="info"

Another approach that I could think of is to create my own Button that wraps the bootstrap Button and that way I can have access to the inner state and use `onClick` inside to control each buttons state, but I'm not sure if that will work, as then how would I restore the other buttons that werent clicked..?

Comment: To be able to access the "info" you could simply add that as a parameter in your handleClick e.g. `onClick = { () => {...otherfunctions, handleClick("info")}`

But that doesn't necessarily solve your initial problem.

Comment: You probably want to create a button component which controls its own state and depending on that state sets/unsets the current colour...

Comment: @Kitson yeah I thought about the wrapping, and that would let me change the variant property when a button is clicked, but, when a button is clicked the previously clicked button should also restore its variant. Also handleClick("info") just gives me info as a string, I want to change the variant property of the button from info to something else when the button is clicked, and when another button gets clicked it should go back to info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Kitson response is a good way to handle your buttons state locally :)

I like to handle the generation of multiple elements with a function. It allows me to customize handleClick.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [buttons, setButtons] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      variant: "info"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      variant: "alert"
    }
  ]);

  const handleClick = id => {
    setButtons(previous_buttons => {
      return previous_buttons.map(b => {
        if (b.id !== id) return b;
        return {
          id,
          variant: "other color"
        };
      });
    });
  };

  const generateButtons = () => {
    return buttons.map(button => {
      return (
        <button key={button.id} onClick={() => handleClick(button.id)}>
          Hey {button.id} - {button.variant}
        </button>
      );
    });
  };
  return <div>{generateButtons()}</div>;
}
```

https://jrjvv.csb.app/

Comment: Thanks this worked, with the only addition to the if, since I want them to behave as radio buttons, in the if I now return the same object, just with the default variant, to restore the original color when that particular button is no longer selected.

Comment: const handleClick = (id) => {
    setButtons((prevButtons) => {
      return prevButtons.map((button) => {
        if (button.id !== id)
          return {
            ...button,
            variant: "info",
          };

        return {
          ...button,
          variant: "success",
        };
      });
    });
  };

Answer (score 3):

To further from my comment above, you could create your own button component to handle its own state and remove the need to have lots of state variables in your main component e.g.

```
const ColourButton = ({ children }) => {
  const [colour, setColour] = React.useState(true)
  return (
    <button
      onClick={ () => setColour(!colour) }
      style = {{color: colour ? "red" : "blue"} }
    >
      { children }
    </button>
  )
}
```

That way you can just wrap your image in your new ColourButton:

```
<ColourButton><img src={square} alt={".."} /></ColourButton>
```

**Edit:**
I actually like to use styled-components and pass a prop to them rather than change the style prop directly. e.g. https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props

Comment: Thanks, altho Juliens answer solved my problem, I will take a look into styled components!

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain a state variable for your selected button.

```
export default class ButtonGroup extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  selected: null
};
}
handleClick = e => {
this.setState({
  selected: e.target.name
});
};
render() {
const selected = this.state.selected;
return (
  <>
    <button
      name="1"
      style={{ backgroundColor: selected == 1 ? "red" : "blue" }}
      onClick={this.handleClick}
    />
    <button
      name="2"
      style={{ backgroundColor: selected == 2 ? "red" : "blue" }}
      onClick={this.handleClick}
    />
    <button
      name="1"
      style={{ backgroundColor: selected == 3 ? "red" : "blue" }}
      onClick={this.handleClick}
    />
  </>
 );
 }
 }
```

Here is a working demo:
https://codesandbox.io/live/OXm3G